# ASP.Net MVC access JWT claims inside view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, jwt

I have propperly implemented a JWT authentication with my Asp.Net Web API. However, I am unsure how to use it together with my MVC application. Let me explain to you how I did it before. Once the user logged in, I saved the user inside a session.

```
// Add user to session
Session["User"] = MyUser;
```

And inside my view I did accesed it like this:

```
@{
    var user = (User)Session["User"];
}
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<h4>@user.FirstName @user.LastName</h4>
```

Now I changed it saving a JWT token in a cookie once the user logged in like this:

```
HttpCookie UserCookie = new HttpCookie("UserCookie");
UserCookie.Value = JWTToken;
UserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
```

My JWT token has several claims which I want to access in my views like I did before with the session. How is that possible? Would someone suggest a different way?

Comment: I suggest you to examine your JWT on the controller side, prepare what you want to give to your view in a ViewBag and let the view access the properties of the ViewBag.

Comment: I like that idea a lot!! Thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0):

you can access them in your controller like that

```
var claimsPrincipal= (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
// Get the claims values
string value = claimsPrincipal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "your key").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

then pass them to your view

don't forget to update your `using`

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading;
```